# I need help translating as I'm Confused with かのような

Tags: translation, conjunctions

So I'm trying to translate a sentence that contains the following hiragana at the end of the first part:

> かのような

and I'm not sure if its 'kano - particle' followed by 'like/similar to', or if かのような means "as if" according to this link: [how to translate 動詞+かのような+名詞?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21169/how-to-translate-%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e%e3%81%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa%e5%90%8d%e8%a9%9e)

Edit: for contextual purposes, the sentence that came before the one I need help with is the following.

> 女の方は黙{だま}っている.

Which I translated as: 'The woman is silent.'

The full sentence I'm trying to translate is

> 品定めをするかのような, 射{い}貫{ね}くような眼差{まなざ}しをこちらに向けながら.

I roughly translated the second part:

> 射{い}貫{ね}くような眼差{まなざ}しをこちらに向けながら

as

'to shoot a penetrating, pointed gaze this way/at me."

but its the first part I'm having much trouble with.

I know that  品定め means "evaluate", and that をする is either a wo/o particle followed by する (which can mean a lot of things but I'm going with 'to judge as being/to do') or some odd verb-no-particle combination of 'を' & 'する', but the rest of the translation depends on what かのような means in the context of this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure if its 'kano - particle' followed by 'like/similar to', ***or*** if かのような means "as if" according to this link:

Not sure what you mean by 'kano - particle' followed by 'like/similar to'.  There is only one usage to 「Verb + かのような」 and that is to form a metaphorical expression or simile as I stated in the linked Q & A.

> 「品定{しなさだ}めをするかのような, 射{い}貫{ぬ}くような眼差{まなざ}しをこちらに向{む}けながら」

「品定めをするかのような」 modifies 「眼差し」 here (and 「射貫くような」 also modifies 「眼差し」).

「品定めをする」(= "***to size someone up***") is only what the speaker feels that the other personis doing.  The speaker never knows if that is the actual intention of the other person.  Hence, the use of 「～～かのような」.

> "while gazing in my direction as if to size me up or to shoot me"

Comment: I'm relatively new to translating Japanese, and the tanoshiijapanese online dictionary I was using to translate "品定めをするかのような" said that する translates to " like / similar to", and that one of the translations for かの in するかのような is as a particle. Seeing as how I didn't know if the かの at the end of the する was a particle or not, I wanted some clarification as to what it was.
 I didn't know that "品定めをする" meant "to size someone up", all three of my online Japanese to English sources failed to give a full translation for the entire phrase or gave something completely out of context.